# Download a file while also updating a JProgressBar

Tags: java, file, download, jprogressbar

I have tried tones of different methods to get this to work but they either don't work with a progress bar or don't work the way I would like it to.

I have already created a new window with a progress bar and need to create a method which would allow me to download a file while also updating a `JProgressBar`. There is an Apache Commons method that is extremely easy to use for downloading files but it doesn't seem to be compatible with `JProgressBar`'s.

I have also had trouble when running this in another thread, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` doesn't seem to update to progress bar, but it does run as I can get it to print to the console. I have even tried the `progressBar.repaint()` method.

So what I would like is a method that can download a file while also updating a `JProgressBar` to reflect the status of the download.

Thanks in advance!
Keir

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/15-javax-swing/1391-how-to-create-a-download-manager-in-java.html) article, I can suggest you to write a `Download class`, which can update a progress bar easily.

This is the `Download` class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

// This class downloads a file from a URL.
class Download extends Observable implements Runnable {

// Max size of download buffer.
private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

// These are the status names.
public static final String STATUSES[] = {"Downloading",
"Paused", "Complete", "Cancelled", "Error"};

// These are the status codes.
public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;
public static final int PAUSED = 1;
public static final int COMPLETE = 2;
public static final int CANCELLED = 3;
public static final int ERROR = 4;

private URL url; // download URL
private int size; // size of download in bytes
private int downloaded; // number of bytes downloaded
private int status; // current status of download

// Constructor for Download.
public Download(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
    size = -1;
    downloaded = 0;
    status = DOWNLOADING;

    // Begin the download.
    download();
}

// Get this download's URL.
public String getUrl() {
    return url.toString();
}

// Get this download's size.
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

// Get this download's progress.
public float getProgress() {
    return ((float) downloaded / size) * 100;
}

// Get this download's status.
public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

// Pause this download.
public void pause() {
    status = PAUSED;
    stateChanged();
}

// Resume this download.
public void resume() {
    status = DOWNLOADING;
    stateChanged();
    download();
}

// Cancel this download.
public void cancel() {
    status = CANCELLED;
    stateChanged();
}

// Mark this download as having an error.
private void error() {
    status = ERROR;
    stateChanged();
}

// Start or resume downloading.
private void download() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

// Get file name portion of URL.
private String getFileName(URL url) {
    String fileName = url.getFile();
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}

// Download file.
public void run() {
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        // Open connection to URL.
        HttpURLConnection connection =
                (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Specify what portion of file to download.
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
                "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

        // Connect to server.
        connection.connect();

        // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
        if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
            error();
        }

        // Check for valid content length.
        int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength < 1) {
            error();
        }

  /* Set the size for this download if it
     hasn't been already set. */
        if (size == -1) {
            size = contentLength;
            stateChanged();
        }

        // Open file and seek to the end of it.
        file = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url), "rw");
        file.seek(downloaded);

        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
    /* Size buffer according to how much of the
       file is left to download. */
            byte buffer[];
            if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            } else {
                buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
            }

            // Read from server into buffer.
            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
                break;

            // Write buffer to file.
            file.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloaded += read;
            stateChanged();
        }

  /* Change status to complete if this point was
     reached because downloading has finished. */
        if (status == DOWNLOADING) {
            status = COMPLETE;
            stateChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error();
    } finally {
        // Close file.
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // Close connection to server.
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}

// Notify observers that this download's status has changed.
private void stateChanged() {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
}
```

As you can see, this `Download` class has got some specific fields like `size` and `downloaded`.

In some other method you could write:

```
JProgressBar j = new JProgressBar(0,download.getSize());
```

After this you could start a new `Thread`, which does update your progress bar at a certain interval, like every 10 ms, with

```
j.setValue(download.getDownloaded());
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I know is a little bit of time from answer post, but, where is located getFileName(url) in line
    file = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url), "rw");

If I replace getFileName(url) with path of my file where I want to save downloaded file, it does not do anything.. I don't understand how to save downloaded file. Please a little help.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, so it's ok. It was my fault, setting in a wrong way the path of file to save to.

Answer (score 4):

downloading the file in a new thread works fine:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

/**
 * 
 * @author adyliu(imxylz@gmail.com)
 * @since 2012-12-28
 */
public class JProgressBarDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JProgressBar pbFile = new JProgressBar();
        pbFile.setValue(0);
        pbFile.setMaximum(100);
        pbFile.setStringPainted(true);
        pbFile.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Download file"));

        JFrame theFrame = new JFrame("ProgressBar Demo");
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = theFrame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(pbFile, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        final JButton btnDownload = new JButton("Download");
        contentPane.add(btnDownload);
        final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        btnDownload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                running.set(!running.get());
                btnDownload.setText(running.get() ? "Pause" : "Continue");
                if (running.get()) {
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            //download file in a thread
                            int v = 0;
                            while (running.get() && v < pbFile.getMaximum()) {
                                pbFile.setValue(++v);
                                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(200));
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }
        });
        theFrame.setSize(300, 150);
        theFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        theFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```