# java progressbar for multiple file downloads

Tags: java, swing, timer, progress-bar

I have to make a little p2p programm for a project. Everything works fine. I have set it up that the client can download multiple files at once(download use threads). My issue is now how can I actually get the overall progress of the download. I tried like this but it doesnt work

```
try {
                int bytesRead;
                InputStream in = mySocket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(("./download/" + filename));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int currentProgress = 0;
                while (filesize > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, filesize))) != -1) {                       
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    filesize -= bytesRead;
                    currentProgress = (int) ((((double)filesize) / ((double)size)) * 100d);
                    currentProgress = ((100-currentProgress)/ViewClient.countFiles);
                    System.out.println(currentProgress);
                }
                output.close();
                in.close();
                System.out.println("File "+filename+" received from client.");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

with this each value(0,1,2,3) will be printed like 100 times and then my progress bar goes sometime up to 2'000'000 depends on the files. How can I get the overall downloaded content?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a JProgressBar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069848/download-a-file-while-also-updating-a-jprogressbar

Comment: Think about it this way, you have `n` number of downloads, each will produce a progress of between 0-100%.  Let's make it 0-1, which will be easier to deal with.  Basically, you then need to take that as a percentage of the whole, so that when all the tasks are completed, it will equal `1`

Comment: Okay, lets say you have `10` tasks, each task is currently at `50%` (`0.5`).  The same of these tasks would be `5`, divide this by `10` (the number of tasks) and you are 50% of the way through the overall progress

Comment: Yep I tried, but I dont really use a progress. I use a glasspane where I paint the progress manually. And because for each download I open a new socket I dont really know how to deal with it. I already have set it up that the download only takes his percentage(so for example if there are 2 downloads each of them only goes to 50% and not each till 100%). Any idea?

Comment: From the sounds of things what you really need is some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you have `n` number of task, each which will generate a progress of between 0-100%.

To make things simple, I'll work with the the idea of 0-1 as the progress value.

You  take the progress of each task and sum it, you then divide this by the number of tasks, which will give you an over all progress of between `0-1`, for example...

```
int taskCount = 10;
List<Double> taskProgress = new ArrayList<>(taskCount);
for (int index = 0; index < taskCount; index++) {
    taskProgress.add(0.0);
}

double overallProgress = 0;
int round = 0;
do {
    round++;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < taskCount; index++) {
        double progress = taskProgress.get(index);
        progress += Math.random() * 0.1;
        progress = Math.min(progress, 1.0);
        sum += progress;
        taskProgress.set(index, progress);
    }
    overallProgress = sum / (double)taskCount;
    System.out.println("[" + round + "] " + NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(overallProgress) + "; " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(overallProgress));
} while (overallProgress < 1.0);
```

Which could print...

```
[1] 5%; 0.049
[2] 9%; 0.09
[3] 14%; 0.144
[4] 18%; 0.179
[5] 23%; 0.23
[6] 28%; 0.276
[7] 32%; 0.321
[8] 37%; 0.366
[9] 40%; 0.403
[10] 45%; 0.451
[11] 51%; 0.505
[12] 55%; 0.552
[13] 60%; 0.601
[14] 64%; 0.642
[15] 69%; 0.695
[16] 76%; 0.761
[17] 80%; 0.803
[18] 84%; 0.845
[19] 87%; 0.869
[20] 90%; 0.902
[21] 92%; 0.925
[22] 95%; 0.946
[23] 96%; 0.962
[24] 97%; 0.971
[25] 98%; 0.976
[26] 99%; 0.986
[27] 99%; 0.989
[28] 99%; 0.993
[29] 100%; 1
```

**Updated with Swing based example**

So, this basically uses a `SwingWorker` to perform a background task, this basically increments a progress value by a random amount (and then pauses for a random amount of time).  The worker provides notification of the progress change via it's `publish`/`process` methods, which provides notification back to interested parties, but does so from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The example makes use of a simple `interface`, which is passed to the `SwingWorker` to allow it to provide notification back to another party about changes to the progress state.  The UI then maintains information about each worker's progress in a `Map`, which is used to calculate the `sum` and resulting total progress.  Essentially the same concept above, just in a more dynamic example

[image: Progress]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ProgressTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressTest();
    }

    public ProgressTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ProgressMonitor{

        private Map<DownloadWorker, Double> workerProgress;
        private int taskCount;
        private double progress;

        public TestPane() {
            workerProgress = new HashMap<>(25);
            taskCount = 10;
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                DownloadWorker worker = new DownloadWorker(index, this);
                workerProgress.put(worker, 0d);
                worker.execute();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = (int)Math.round(getWidth() * progress);
            g2d.setColor(UIManager.getColor("ProgressBar.selectionBackground"));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void progressWasUpdated(DownloadWorker worker, double progress) {
            workerProgress.put(worker, progress);
            double sum = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<DownloadWorker, Double> entry : workerProgress.entrySet()) {
                sum += entry.getValue();
            }
            this.progress = sum / (double)taskCount;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public interface ProgressMonitor {
        public void progressWasUpdated(DownloadWorker worker, double progress);
    }

    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public class DownloadWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Double> {

        private int index;
        private ProgressMonitor progressMonitor;

        public DownloadWorker(int index, ProgressMonitor progressMonitor) {
            this.progressMonitor = progressMonitor;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            double progress = 0;
            do {
                progress += Math.random() * 0.1;
                progress = Math.min(progress, 1.0);
                publish(progress);
                Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(490) + 10);
            } while (progress < 1.0);
            publish(1.0);
            System.out.println(index + " has ended");
            return null;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Double> chunks) {
            progressMonitor.progressWasUpdated(this, chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }

    }

}
```

For the purpose of the example, each worker is provide with a `int` index, this can be used to provide some additional debugging so you can see how each is updated

Comment: the problem is that I cannot say that after 1 cycle of the loop it increment by 1. Im reading byte arrays. My output looks like this and I dont know how to fix it that it shows only 0,1,2,3.... So each value is printed like 100 time. for example that a part of my output: 23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24

Comment: I assume that you know the total number of bytes you are reading?  If not, then there is no way you can calculate the percentage (`bytesRead / totalBytesToBeRead`).  If so, then the example code will work, you just need to break it down so that on each read cycle, you calculate a new progress value of between 0-1 for then given task, then based on that you can calculate the overall progress for all the tasks. And yes, I do this all the time :P

Comment: yeah dont worry, your solution is great =). I know the filesizes, so how many bytes. It depends on the file size but the while loop can goes up to 157'000 loops. So it prints the current progress in my example with the test file 157000 times which will go cleary over the 100% or in your case if I divide for 100 the 1. And I dont know how to fix it =(